# WPF ListBox display last item differently

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate, controltemplate

I want to have a listbox, that allows the user to fetch lets say 20 items from the DB and displays a hint on the last row of the listbox if there are more items to be fetched. When the user clicks on this last row, additional items should be retrieved from the DB, until there aren't any more and the last line displays this information.

First:

```
listitem1
listitem2
...
listitem19
listitem20
Button: <get_more>
```

after button press:

```
listitem1
listitem2
...
listitem39
listitem40
Info: <no more items>
```

Could all this be done in XAML only? 
What would be the best solution to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Dude -- **Everything** can be done with XAML :D

Following a MVVM approach, I'd recommend you to do the following:

1/ Getting started: A `DockPanel`

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
   <ListBox  />
</DockPanel>
```

2/ Bind your `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListElements}" />
```

In the ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _listElements;

        public ObservableCollection<String> ListElements
        {
            get { return _listElements; }
            set { _listElements = value; }
        }
```

3/ Bind your `Button`'s content to a predefined `String`:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonString}" />
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public String ButtonString
{
   get 
   {
      //There, define if there are any more things to display
   }
}
```

4/ Your `Button` fires a `Command` launching a method, let's say `GetMore()` :

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonString}" Command="{Binding GetMoreCommand} />
```

In ViewModel:

```
private void GetMore()
{
   //append to the _listElements new elements from the list 
   //Update the ButtonString if there are no more elements
}
```

And there you go!

(you can also, if needed, define a button removing things from the `ObservableCollection` for example)

Comment: Thanks @Damascus. Your solution will definitely work, but having the Button outside the listbox has some disadvantages: they are both in a view which has a vertical scroollbar, which in your case I think would be the DockPanel's scrollbar. I want the scrolling to be done on the ListBox, so that for instance I can use the scroll wheel to do the scrolling directly in the listbox.

Comment: You can display the scroll bar just for the list. That's actually the purpose in putting the button aside from the ListBox. Just remove the scrollbar from your dockPanel (I'm not sure that there is a `IsScrollable` property, but at least you can set the `Scrollviewer.VerticalScrollbarVisibility` to `Hidden` for the `DockPanel`, the list will therefore handle it

Comment: The problem is that I want to have the listbox and the button in a limited view (lets say 100 pixels). The listbox extends to lets say 1000 pixels, then comes the button. I place both the listbox and the button into a StackPanel, which is placed inside a ScrollViewer. Doing this actually is OK, except I am not able to scroll using the mouse wheel! It seems the mouse wheel event is catched by the listbox (which does nothing because it is expanded) and the event doesn't bubble up to the scrollviewer. Maybe I should fix this problem, not search for other solutions :)

Comment: I think the problem there is more on your layout than on the process itself, You can easily use what I gave you and just change the first part, in XAML. I'd say that this is a focus problem, have you tried setting explicitly the focus to your scrollviewer?